# Can I set default security and/or branch policies in Azure DevOps?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

We're using [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/) for our git server.  Each Azure DevOps Project hosts one or many git repos.  We have the convention of keeping `master` and `develop` branches locked-down, but letting other branches remain unrestricted.

I'd like to be able to apply our standard rules at the project-level and have them be the defaults for all repos within them:

- `master` and `develop` should have their security deny `Force Push`
- `master` branch requires a Pull Request via a Code Review policy

So far the **only** option I've found is to manually set these per-repository, through the web-interface (not even an API!).  We have at least 200+ repositories and would love to avoid having to manually setup every repo and branch one by one.

How do I set default code security and code policies by branch name?  Or by any way other than manually?

Answer (score 15):

- For setting branch policies with minimum reviewers for multiple git repositories across a team project (project-level), you can use REST API. Detail steps as below:

**1. [Get all git repositories](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/repositories#get-a-list-of-repositories) for the team project.**

```
GET https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/ProjectName/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=1.0
```

Then save each git repo id and name from output.

**2. Loop the repositories you got in step1 in your code by repo id, and [create branch policy](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/policy/configurations#create-a-policy-configuration) for each master branch** (assume the minimum number of reviewers is 2 here).

```
POST https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/ProjectName/_apis/policy/configurations?api-version=2.0-preview
```

Application/json:

```
{
  "isEnabled": true,
  "isBlocking": true,
  "type": {
    "id": "fa4e907d-c16b-4a4c-9dfa-4906e5d171dd"
  },
  "settings": {
                "minimumApproverCount": 2,
                "creatorVoteCounts": false,
                "allowDownvotes": false,
                "scope": [
                    {
                        "refName": "refs/heads/master",
                        "matchKind": "Exact",
                        "repositoryId": "{repo id}"
                    }
                ]
  }
}
```

- For setting branch security (force push as deny), there is no such REST API, and I posted an user voice [Set branch security by REST API](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/20285419-set-branch-security-by-rest-api), you can vote and follow up.

Comment: To script the branch security, see: https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-git-setting-default-repository-permissions/

Comment: You can also set the `repositoryId` to `null` to apply it to all current and future repositories.

Comment: You can set the branch filter to `prefix` to configure all feature branches or all release branches as long as you adopt a common naming pattern. See: https://jessehouwing.net/azure-repos-git-configuring-standard-policies-on-repositories/

Answer (score 5):

To script the Repository and branch security, you can use the `tfssecurity.exe` or the new permissions REST API or the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/devops/security). [All details in the following blog post](https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-git-setting-default-repository-permissions/):

For specific branches, add `/refs^heads^master/` at the end of the Token.

### Excerpt

If you've dug into the security innards of Azure DevOps in the past, you'll have found out that certain permissions are granted to persons or groups and are linked to a token. This token is usually built up out of a root object and a bunch of GUIDs. For example, this is the token for a specific Git Repository:

```
repoV2/daec401a-49b6-4758-adb5-3f65fd3264e3/f59f38e0-e8c4-45d5-8dee-0d20e7ada1b7
^      ^                                    ^
|      |                                    |
|      |                                    -- The Git Repository
|      -- The Team Project Guid
|
-- The root object (Repositories)
```

Simplest way I know of to find these details, is to capture the web request made when a permission is changed:

[image]

You can use the Web Developer tools in your favorite browser to find the token you need.
Once you understand this, it's easy to find the token for the "All Repositories in a Team Project" token. Just take off the Git Repository GUID at the end:

```
repoV2/daec401a-49b6-4758-adb5-3f65fd3264e3b7/
^      ^                                    
|      |                                    
|      -- The Team Project Guid
|
-- The root object (Repositories)
```

And, using the same reasoning, to get to the token for "All repositories in the Project Collection/Organization" token. Just take off the Team Project GUID at the end:

```
repoV2/
^                                          
|
-- The root object (Repositories)
```

And now that we have this token, we can use tfssecurity to set Organization level git permissions:

```
tfssecurity /a+ "Git Repositories" repoV2/ "PullRequestBypassPolicy" adm: ALLOW /collection:https://dev.azure.com/org
            ^   ^                  ^       ^                         ^    ^
            |   |                  |       |                         |    -- Allow or Deny the permission 
            |   |                  |       |                         -- The Group (in this case "Project Collection Administrators")
            |   |                  |       -- The Permission we want to set
            |   |                  -- The Token we found above
            |   -- The Secuity Namespace
            -- Add  (a+) or Remove (a-) this permission
```

And, as you can see below, this trick actually works :).

[image]

You can use the same technique to secure branches. The token of a branch uses the token of the Repository as a basis and adds the branch to that. Because a `/` is a token separator, a branch reference is escaped by replacing `/` with `^`. Thus `refs/heads/master` becomes: `refs^heads^master`:

```
repoV2/daec401a-49b6-4758-adb5-3f65fd3264e3/f59f38e0-e8c4-45d5-8dee-0d20e7ada1b7/refs^heads^master/
^      ^                                    ^                                    ^
|      |                                    |                                    |
|      |                                    |                                    -- The branch
|      |                                    -- The Git Repository
|      -- The Team Project Guid
|
-- The root object (Repositories)
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by a recent update, you can now configure this through the UI itself.

> Now, admins can set policies on a specific branch or the default
>   branch across all repositories in their project.

Simply go to the "Project Settings" => "Cross-repo Policies".

[image]

The only caveat is, being a recent change this will only be available curently on the Azure Devops cloud service and not on Azure Devops server deployments. So if you are on the server version, you may need to wait for sometime.

You may refer this url: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/repos/sprint-160-update